# MATLAB OOP, can I call calling class methods?

Tags: oop, matlab

For example:
I have two classes like this:
Look for a question inside class B comment, down.

```
classdef A < handle
    properties
        classBobj; % class B is a property of class A
    end

    methods
        MethodFromA (obj)
        end
    end
end

classdef B <handle
    methods
        MethodFromB (obj)
            % I is possible to call class A method MethodFromA here
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What's the error you are running into? Also the class def is not valid matlab code.

Comment: What do you mean?
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/classdef.html

I just want to call the method defined in class A from within class B. Class B is a property of class A. Just as in example code above.

Comment: Well obviously you can run `objectA.MethodFromA()`. Try to give at a simple working example (current one isn't) then we can discuss the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways in which this is possible:

1. You try to call a static method from class A but then you have to define it as such:

   ```
   classdef A < handle

       properties
           classBobj; % class B is a property of class A
       end

       methods (Static)
           MethodFromA()
       end

   end
   ```

This can be called everywhere in your code (without a reference to an instance of A) as follows `A.MethodFromA()`

2. You have a reference to an instance of class A within your so instead of calling `MethodFromB(obj)`, you should all `MethodFromB(obj, classAobj)`

Comment: This will not work unfortunately, as I want method
`MethodFromA()`
to actually access the object created from A.

Comment: Matlab does not have functionality to have inner classes. If you want to acces the object created from A then you need to have at least a reference to it.

Comment: Is it possible to create a global reference to MethodFromA()?